# Find key nodes in Graph Neural Netwroks

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weights, graph-neural-network

[image: Task illustration]

Given a graph dataset, in which links of graphs are the same while features of each node may be varied, how can we locate those critical nodes in this graph structure that contribute the most to impact the classification?